# Centering javascript/html text 50%/50% width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having this problem where I can't center this text no matter what I use, here is the code,
I want `item1` and `item` on each side width wise (left and right) to be centered

Picture of the full `vh` [edit picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waY13.png)

EDIT2: I have already tried, `justify-content: space-between` and `space-around` so that doesen't work neither does the `grid` layout.

EDIT3: Defined `questionTextElement`

```js
const items = [
  { name: "Ferrari Portofino 2021", value: 250000, imageSrc: "https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/K0DGSuoYmpv34Jli04xH2g5nGfk=/0x0:5385x3029/1000x1000/filters:focal(2693x1515:2694x1516)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/22780648/COUNTACH_LPI800_4__2_.jpg" },
  { name: "Lamborghini Gallardo", value: 126000, imageSrc: "https://di-uploads-pod30.dealerinspire.com/bmwofschererville/uploads/2021/10/1-BMW-Exterior-1000x1000-Oct2021.png" },
  // Add more items and their values here
];

let item1, item2, correctIndex;
const item1Element = document.getElementById("item1");
const item2Element = document.getElementById("item2");
const questionTextElement = document.getElementById("question-text");
  questionTextElement.innerHTML = `${item2.name} &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;${item1.name}`;
  document.getElementById("item1").textContent = item1.name + " " + formatCurrency(item1.value);
  document.getElementById("item2").textContent = item2.name + " " + formatCurrency(item2.value);
```

```css
 .question-text {
    
    color: white;
    display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(0%, 350%);
    width: 98vw;
    font-family: 'RooneySans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 3rem;

}
```

```html
 <div class="gameStarted">
        <div class="line"><p class="vs">VS</p></div>
        <div id="score-container" class="score-container">
           <p id="score-text" class="score-text">Score: 0</p>
       </div>
        <h2 id="question-text" class="question-text">
       
            <span class="item">${item2.name} ${item2.value}</span>
            <span class="space">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
            <span class="item">${item1.name} ${item1.value}</span>
        
        </h2>

        <h3 id="valueIndex">
            <span class="value">${item2.value}</span> 
            <span class="space">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
            <span class="value">${item1.value}</span> 
        </h3>
        
        
            <div class="the-images">
                <img id="item1" class="item" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pw/ADCreHcCjus21gcwf_7ZWtWnI1C8VF6il_oIJ5L0yCIuR-I5YOr_ZGzZLL14BeTxWL4TfNr1nwJqkdsQiIUjeTOrj9RNKSN-05eq91gQP4fWrPSKlqOeXcXdkZtKd1F0UlLruAfupEnybDoKx7BnduYLYM32LEZPy_qJqJoABqE4lhytYWFyo-uMbZ8GlV3IjTl4fWwRNT1hKMiQoX2J0marXDA5CrtrRq9nJQE0nH2rtSCSwZmJnCQc0PrEmeA_Rg5Ss6gDzvpwWr7dQmH0IfUCXxZiJl1HFNYGCoSr2Rm79hKdVJPlLWeaevPgwDJ7Yy9igO6IdMc77QNax3jA93bMYqkChm2wa40ev8HPs7h2Q_nteXUFq_b1r2I7ap866gONYBdE0qeZcd0uSudyzTgIyz9VTsiDKxIItR7aljYE_BfL2QZHKYWmqSvuxLx0FM85qczVPcH1BI-T3goi5EvvUOcKeTUJt3sUdZsr_LQoMPlYEa2bvQcTGlypCMI7hcTYOLwNPsKV1RFCJu4MxlcnLEO6S8S9dB6CkSPZQhijU_gxXehMkj64EdCVcOlzIda1r5HegE7KaHEEoxAv8XbhM0qpnjeQrMs1an8jNqAR6IL3LW-tcQlsGljFCf_XNp0adrHsLSlvablMdiRokWnYlU3dton4yw5-3KXPdr8G-EVSrTLf1C8HAZvRx0eoSTHEJD-hxjRbieVyzhHeSjBJ6mZGIHbfnwuhudLyxYlEPZkqWRAUin-oh_iQcNXSs_wLko-XCoDt0gllXM27oa5tdvfJk4PiUKBO-fa25MCxF0G4P8aKOh_WKPkIddRswVhUh3aTPNI6O9JbDJpgeA6n-pGx8vf1lS_e79wxFjcFJAoPtvxl423aB4Oe-xCZbZlVrVMJZPQAkOhFtOQOcNSZ1yq5XH9H6bz2G9q-g_I2BkCb1KwKJ5cftOR7vg=w707-h353-s-no?authuser=0" alt="Item 1">
                <img id="item2" class="item" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pw/ADCreHdP1_Kf_n02AGb882NS26oo4NnFmqUylj7ww8ecIoHje6Zl4z_uQ8_z8KpfF126leO4l_TImfWiy0dTE0CYApw_dekxeH6XedeRv3iMrrBfCm0Ds2BhakRUXStwNm8_YyNN4fcl3NnlLpN1jMls1ixO0-WG0hmshnuFgygug-qvuMyd8hpQW1HKwslTr-zPBn2M6t_odmoQUQAWQseNysVvrCo7me-9lnfmumG17oFie0S6Pj7mEE_q4BwiYk4fQ8iYxfiuDyGdbLlR6VmRdvkf7BlbZqA417AAdzyWohLSZoU2aY_K0EP0b-7oZF76AQYc6kQE-nd2QU9nhBT9Ij6SLNLdavFUQck4uqZzVSgUXPo81hGPpeywq_FF3ll37TlEMWnQSgSEm80xgmGP7KkWK-OIVpF_-CHrCqB-18d5LnRcut48HXjqPeJRXzxRntB0HVCFvq0nZWbI2OiMF3ILJWp09gyQWr3zLsM5CfDm3NWmVLy4LUg3BNNfJ9BdBNH0TdyFzEH6vxlQkaEtVY86K9eMJVc9tqt1T6LeBXxh55YtK0XVO7Kq7Wk0JUAh6J_OqqSMtZNBYEDPOge0FXLuGLXXlZ-hDxYQjlOA4-J6ALAEY6qlcKdQu_iG6sDToC0nBlbAUmq0JYk194q8ojYxfHps-HoYCZxFeauawiC2mY49omlR_YEslegwi79DMOttecI56CdqWK6Syd_mOsd57lM9eJJ4_r2U3BUC1YHfL8bEVIAqqYQJCwkMP1wa8UYbc3gjDpmQBNNZ_dMvT2rnlYBH-S46BCeYnJH_WHPzK0NXLY5p7Qtk41o2EFoyX0843UySheVz_oRAWzQdY0-nt4DNIPOeNo7WSBqtRF9e00UevzidggdRcgZgLU4xacjkkpy6k7YhY9xsFlwUfuXvm6uuBVSAtJN3m9Gg630Jn6QgX1lb7LOn7A=w654-h381-s-no?authuser=0" alt="Item 2">
            </div>
```

I have tried css-wise everything i just dont know how to seperate these 2 elements and then center each of them on their own, thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: You have an error : `questionTextElement is not defined`

Comment: @MisterJojo bru

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Here's a [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) you might find useful...

Comment: You've updated your question, but we still can't run your snippet because `questionTextElement` is undefined.

Comment: i added that in

Comment: Your snippet still doesn't run. It's missing a closing `]`, `item2` is not defined. If you are stuck on a syntax error, ask about that, but we can only guess based on the code that's here.

Comment: yeah, i need alot of things, maybe i just paste the whole code in?

Comment: Just the relevant pieces; we shouldn't have to wade through everything to debug.

Comment: fixed it now its kind of working?

Comment: Please run the snippet on your question and read the error message. You have declared variables but not defined them.

Comment: i still dont understnad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `justify-content: space-around` to add spacing around. If you don't want the space around, use `space-between` instead.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.question-text {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="question-text" class="question-text">
  <span class="item">Foo</span>
  <span class="item">Bar</span>
</div>
```

You could also use a grid layout:

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.question-text {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.question-text > span {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="question-text" class="question-text">
  <span class="item">Foo</span>
  <span class="item">Bar</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello thanks for taking the time to answer but I already tried the space-between and around, it cant be centered like that, the grid layout isn't quite working either